# Primefaces calendar component manually entering date beyond maxdate validation fails

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, calendar

I'm trying to add a Calendar  input component in an application.

The Calendar  input component to pick a datetime and the max date restriction works ie doesn't allow to select future date

- Greys out the future date - works fine / User cannot select a future date

**Problem** is the user can  enter the future date manually, it is not validating this field.

User is able to enter the future date manually

```
5/24/2021
6/2/2020

<p:calendar id="userdate" value="#{calendarView.pricedate}" maxdate="#{calendarView.maxDate}" />
```

calendarView.java

```
private Date maxDate = new Date();

public Date getMaxDate() {
    return maxDate;
}

public void setMaxDate(Date maxDate) {
    this.maxDate = new Date();
}
```

Primefaces Version

```
<primefaces.version>6.2</primefaces.version>
```

How to validate this component when user enters the field value manually, I have added a max date validation attribute.

Comment: Please state your PF version

Comment: So you tried PF 7 or 8? And checked the PF issue list?

Comment: @MatteoZanini The business requirement wants the field in such a way that the user can enter manually and as well as the the Primefaces component like picking the date.

Comment: @MatteoZanini: OP Should try PF 7 or 8 with a [mcve] and check the issuelist (or check the releasenotes of newer versions, but checking the issuelist is more important)  Or use a search engine... https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=maxDate+calendar+validation+primefaces

Comment: The business is looking to keep the application with the current Primefaces Version

Comment: @MatteoZanini: Why did you remove your other answer? It was a good addition. I was just going to upvote it (which I forgot after I edited it)..

Answer (score 2):

A simple search in a search engine of your liking

- [One that tracks you](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=minDate+calendar+validation+primefaces)
- [Or even one that does not track you](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=minDate+calendar+validation+primefaces&ia=web)

  Would have shown

[Calendar: does not validate the input against mindate/maxdate](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3582)

With a fix version of 7.0

And to prove it I created a real full [mcve]:
XHMTL:

```
<h:form>
    <p:messages id="messages"/>
    <p:calendar id="registrationDate" value="#{testView3582.date}" mindate="#{testView3582.minDate}" maxdate="#{testView3582.maxDate}" navigator="true" yearRange="c-2:c" showButtonPanel="true"
        mask="true" styleClass="#{testView3582.maxDate}"/>

    <p:commandButton value="submit" update="messages" />
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
@Named(value = "testView3582")
@ViewScoped
public class TestView implements Serializable {

    Date date;
    Date minDate;
    Date maxDate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -10);
        minDate = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, +20);
        maxDate = cal.getTime();
        
    }

    //Getters/Setters omitted
}
```

With a min/max date of 10 days before now and 10 days past and when manually entering 04/20/20 and pressing submit I get

[image]

Next time please

- Always search the [issue list](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/) (contains a workaround for previous versions, see also the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083276#answer-61099344))
- Always create a real [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- Always try with a newer version (preferably latest)